# Running a Java plugin on macOS similar to Internet Explorer 11 on Windows

Tags: macos, browser, java

I would like to run Java from a website on a browser on macOS 10.13. I am able to run Java on that website on Internet Explorer 11, version 11.1944.14393.0, software update version 11.0.49. I am unable to run it on Safari or Google Chrome, I keep seeing `Java plugin is missing`.

I followed the directions at [Java.com](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.html) to enable it on Safari, but it seems that they are deprecated and that Safari now does not allow running Java. Google Chrome has probably made a similar decision.

I don't think I can install Internet Explorer on macOS. Which version of which browser would I need to install to allow this website to run Java?

Comment: Chrome has not made a similar decision.  Chrome by default will block the content and only enable it if you specifically all it as a user.  Internet Explorer cannot be installed on macOS since it only exists on Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you say more about allowing Chrome to specifically allow it as a user?

Comment: There is a button, when the content is blocked, to allow the content